# compresse a SHA256 digest to 16 unique char

Tags: compression, converters, token, sha256

i'm working in crypto and i want to tokenize a SHA256 digest to 16 or Plus Char , so i want to ask you if you have any idea to compresse or crypte the Digest or if i can have 114bit from 256bit it will be great to do get the tokenize .

thank you

Cdt,
aia

Comment: You cannot compress the hash to a fixed length without discarding information.

Comment: thnk you , i know that it's impossible to do it. I explane in an other way , if i have a char[16] in clear, I cipher it to a fixed lenght , after that i use a method to get 114bit , if i hade that I can apply a Base64 encode and i get a token between 16 an 20 carctar